# Troubles with Curlpp

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, curlpp

When i'm compiling this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>

int main() {
    cURLpp :: Cleanup cleanup;
    std :: cout << "Hello world" << std :: endl;

    return 0;
}
```

via console:

```
g++ main.cpp -lcurlpp
```

there are lot's of errors such as:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurlpp.so: undefined reference to `curl_getenv@CURL_OPENSSL_3'
```

which are connected only with `CURL_OPENSSL_3`

How can i fix it? Thanks

Ubuntu 15.04, curl version - `7.38.00`, curlpp - installed `sudo apt-get install libcurlpp-dev`

Comment: Looks like you need to include other libraries that curlpp depends on.

Comment: @AnonMail Which, for example. I didn't find practical information in the internet about this problem

Comment: based on your command-line I'd guess you are missing `-lcurl`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl sadly, i tried all variants with `-lcurl` and `lcurlpp`, without `lcurlpp` there are mistakes like: `main.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup()'` in all another cases mistakes as in topic

Comment: Well, `-lcurlpp` is implemented in terms of `-lcurl`. So you'd need both `-lcurlpp -lcurl`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl that's what i'm talking about: `g++ main.cpp -lcurl -lcurlpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurlpp.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt@CURL_OPENSSL_3'...........and so on with CURL_OPENSSL_3`

Comment: Library order matters: you certainly need to specify `-lcurl` *after* `-lcurlpp`. I don't have enough context to reproduce the problem (e.g., a test program using `libcurlpp`). I noticed that there are two variations of `libcurl`: one version 3 and one version 4. That *may* also be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mint 17 I was able to compile and run your program using

```
g++ main.cpp -lcurl -lcurlpp
```

Looking at a library dump of the program, you may be missing the following libraries which you can install with `apt-get`:

```
libssl-1.0.0
libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

LD Dump

```
$ ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff701fe000)
    libcurlpp.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurlpp.so.0 (0x00007f896cd05000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f896c9f7000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f896c7df000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f896c41a000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f896c1b3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f896beac000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f896cf68000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f896bc79000)
    librtmp.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.0 (0x00007f896ba5f000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f896b7ff000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f896b424000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f896b1dd000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f896afcd000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f896ad7c000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f896ab63000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f896a944000)
    libgnutls.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26 (0x00007f896a686000)
    libgcrypt.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11 (0x00007f896a406000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f896a201000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f8969f36000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f8969d07000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f8969b02000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f89698f7000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f89696dc000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f89694c0000)
    libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007f8969282000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f896906e000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f8968e2b000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f8968c26000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f8968a22000)
    libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007f8968818000)
    libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007f8968590000)
    libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007f89682ee000)
    libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007f89680bb000)
    libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007f8967ea6000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f8967c9d000)
    libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007f8967a74000)
    libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007f8967866000)
    libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007f896761c000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f8967363000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f896712a000)
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was, that libssl was out of date. Everything works